# Como pasar datos a un modal desde un foreach?

Tags: laravel, modal, blade

Tengo un foreach que muestra un listado de productos con su descripción y su foto y un boton que abre un modal llamado #callMe

```
@foreach ($results['resultadoComparador'] as $result)
.....

<a class="btn-orange text-white shadow d-block mt-3 py-2  px-4  fw-bold text-uppercase mr-auto ml-auto" style="line-height:1;font-size: .875rem; border-width: 1px;border-radius: 0.25rem;" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#callMe">
                                                        Llamenme!
                                                    </a>
@endforeach
```

Ahora bien... tengo el modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="callMe" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="buy" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'contact','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off', 'class'=>'row gy-1 pt-75'))!!}
              {{Form::token()}}
            <div class="contact-advisor">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="w-100 h-100 d-flex">
                        <div class="left-side">
                            <div class="text-white">
                                <div class="position-relative top-0 left-0 w-100 text-center">
                                    <div class="rounded-circle bg-white text-center p-2 mx-4 my-4 mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
                                        style="height: 8rem;width:8rem">
        
                                        <img class="w-100"
                                            src="/products/ {{$result['photo']}}.png" alt="" title=" {{$result['name']}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <h1>Nombre de producto {{$result['name']}}</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el modal quiero que se muestre el nombre del producto, la foto y puedan enviar el formulario..

no logro pasar los datos al modal, solo poniendo el modal dentro del foreach pero si lo hago así se rompe todo.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Tenés 2 opciones: 1) Creas tantos modals como productos tengas, tal vez en otro `foreach` donde cada modal tiene que tener un _ID único_. 2) Creas un solo modal, vacío, y hacés una consulta mediante AJAX para que el backend te devuelva el contenido del modal según el producto que clickees.

Comment: Hola, si eso tengo en claro, es lo que estoy intentando hacer lo que pasa es que estoy estancado en como hacerlo

Comment: Cuando pusiste el modal dentro del foreach te aseguraste de NO estar repitiendo los IDs? A qué te referís con que "se rompe todo"?